# Redis timeout errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have an application which is getting lots of Redis timeout errors thrown.

The way I'm configuring the cache in the Startup.cs is like this:

```
  var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Configuration.GetValue<string>("RedisConnection"));
  services.AddDataProtection(
      options => { options.ApplicationDiscriminator = "my-ap";}
      ).PersistKeysToRedis(redis, "my-ap-data-protection-keys");


  services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
      {
          options.Configuration = Configuration.GetValue<string>("RedisConnection");
      });
```

I'm going through [this document here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/) which mentions the best practice of using Redis is like this:

```
 private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => { 
    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("RedisConnection"); });

public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection { get { return lazyConnection.Value; } }
```

**Part 1 of the question:** It's not really clear to me how I can incorporate this into my code for the distribution keys. Do I just add a static method in my startup class?

**Part 2 of the question:** I am using the `AddDistributedRedisCache` extension method from Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis Version 2.1.2.0 and I can't find the area where the recommended method above is being used

Comment: I'm a bit confused - you're adding the DistributedCache AND the multiplexer?  You should be able to just use the AddDistributedCache setup, and then inject IDistributedCache into your other classes...

Comment: what is your timeout? you'd be amazed how high (and spikey) the latency on cloud providers *can be*

Comment: @MarcGravell how do I find out what the timeout is?

Comment: @MarcGravell IIUC I'm not setting the timeout on the connection string. Its the default value (which I've found is 5000 in some documentation here: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration)

Comment: @MarcGravell looks like ut was the timeouts after all I increased them and it resolved a load of those errors. Thanks. Can you set this as an answer so I can mark it please